# "as" as a conjunction or preposition

Tags: word-usage, as

1: He doesn't play half as well **as** his sister does.

2: He doesn't play half as well **as** his sister.

In sentence one,  the second "as" is a conjunction. Am I right?
In sentence two, should I take the second "as" as a preposition or as a conjunction with "does" being omitted?

Thank you very much!

Comment: More interesting: "as she does" versus "as she/her"

Answer (score 2):

In both sentences, "as" is used as an adverb because it is comparing two things. It is used as a conjunction when something happening continuously over a period of time.

> As he got worked harder, his grades improved.

That is an example of "as" as a conjunction.
"As" is used as a preposition when referring to a characteristic something has.

> They were treated as kings.

Answer (score 1):

> **1:** He doesn't play half as well as his sister does.
>
> **2:** He doesn't play half as well as his sister.

In both the sentences the first ***as*** is an adverb, and the second ***as*** is a preposition.

A preposition can take a Noun Phrase (NP), or a clause or any other grammatical structure as its complement.

The word - ***half*** - before the first ***as*** is a determinative, that modifies - ***as well as his sister does***.

A determinative can modify an adverb phrase -

> I know I haven't done it *that* **well**.

In this sentence ***well*** is an adverb and it's being modified by the determinative - ***that***.

Answer (score 1):

1.As can be conjunction and a preposition depending on what it is connecting. If it is connecting a clause with another clause its a conjunction.
**for example:**
*Choose your carrier as you wish.*
above sentence as is connecting a clause you subject and wish verb.

2.if as is use to connect a noun or phrase, then a preposition.
**for example,**
*Chips was taken as a toddling child.*
in above as is a preposition as connecting a phrase.

Answer (score 0):

The second 'as' of both sentences is conjunction since it is followed by a clause. Regarding the second sentence, you cannot compare 'play' with 'his sister'. They are not commensurable. So the 'does' is omitted.

Comment: Not sure I agree - but I would change #1 to: He doesn't play half as well as does his sister.